# Is there a way of selecting elements by their title in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a program to select elements on the page, but it seems that the only thing that makes them unique are there titles. Is there any way of selecting certain things on a web page by their titles? I found this script but it will not select or click on the elements.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will do. Thanks

How can I get it to work on A and not div, sorry, that was the problem
My script that I am using --

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("a[title=\"Learn More About Becoming A VIP\"]").click();
     });
```

It says `Div is not defined` when I try to run script. Why So?

Comment: Why do you think it doesnt work? I just tried it here and it works. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVRbXN

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code already works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to select elements by their `title` attribute in `javascript`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[title="john"]');
```

## ======

You can also select elements that have a `title` *beginning* with `john`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[title^="john"]');
```

Or elements that have the (space-bounded) word `john` *somewhere* in their title:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[title~="john"]');
```

Comment: it says div is not defined... what does that mean? (Sorry i'm new to js, been using php)

Comment: Make sure you have the correct quotes (double quotes and single quotes) in the right places.

Comment: it works but I can not use .click() function on it. Why is that? Is there a way of doing that? @Rounin

Comment: Are you trying to grab a collection of nodes or a single node? If you just want to grab a single node (ie. the first one), use `document.querySelector`, rather than `document.querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector should work if title value is **john**. You might wan't to select element that contains certain string as follow:

```
$('div[title*="john"]')
```